# Is there an easy way to support OData search with an in-memory storage in C#?

Tags: c#, azure, unit-testing, odata, stub

I am coding in C# against a service which supports search by OData queries - specifically Azure table storage using **Azure.Data.Tables.TableClient**.

When testing my OData query generation logic, it would be convenient to be able to stub out the Azure part and run the queries against an in-memory storage. I can easily make an in-memory storage using collections or dictionaries, but I don't want to have to implement a whole OData interpreter. That would be lots of work and error-prone.

Are there C# libraries that let me easily make my own in-memory storage which I can search using OData queries - i.e., an easy way to check whether an object/entity matches a given OData query?

Answer (score 1):

**ASP.NET Web API Odata** is a framework that makes it easy to build OData services that reach a broad range of clients, including browsers and mobile devices. ASP.NET Web API OData is an ideal platform for building OData applications on the .NET Framework.

**OData for Client** is a LINQ-enabled client API for issuing OData queries and consuming OData JSON payloads. It’s the V4 version of the former WCF Data Services Client for OData v1-3.

OData NuGets used.

[image]

**OData for Client**

[image]

Below is the code snippet.

// Read multiple items from container

```
var prod2 = new Product()
{
    RowKey = "68719518390",
    PartitionKey = "gear-surf-surfboards",
    Name = "Sand Surfboard",
    Quantity = 5,
    Sale = false
};

await tableClient.AddEntityAsync<Product>(prod2);

var products = tableClient.Query<Product>(x => x.PartitionKey == "gear-surf-surfboards");

Console.WriteLine("Multiple products:");
foreach (var item in products)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
}
```

References taken from

[OData Libraries](https://www.odata.org/libraries/)

[Azure Cosmos DB for Table for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table/quickstart-dotnet?tabs=azure-cli,windows#retrieve-all-entities-in-a-partition)

[OData Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/odata/client/getting-started)

Comment: Thanks. How do you create the `tableClient` in your example? Is that of type **Azure.Data.Tables.TableClient**? I need a table that stores my data _in memory_, NOT in Azure table storage. I do not want to consume an external OData service; I want to make my own in-memory service that supports search by OData. From your example it is not clear to me whether I can achieve that.

Comment: If you do not want to use external OData service then, you can use an in-memory data structure such as a Dictionary or List in C# to store your data and implement search functionality.
For more information check this [DataTable Class.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0)

Comment: **DataTable** can solve my problem. If you revise the answer to mention it, I will mark your answer as accepted. :)